# Is there a way to handle the Cannot GET error in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, http

I'm working on a search functionality for my application, but when users type something on the search bar that doesn't exist on the app it redirects them to the "Cannot GET /Search/whatevertheysearch" page. This is ok, but I'd like to handle it with more care. Is there a way to edit the html of this page, or handle the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is basically a `404`, you could handle this by using this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).render('status');
});
```

And in stead of `.render()` you could also use `send()` or `sendFile()`.

Comment: Oh ok perfect! I didn't know if it was it's own kind of error or not, but your suggestion works. Thanks!